# is instanceId globally unique across all AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have been trying to follow other answers where it is mentioned that,instanceIds are unique globally for an account, for each region they might change, but will it be unique globally across multiple AWS accounts?

Comment: If its not explicitly state in docs, then you can't assume that.

Comment: [Is the Amazon EC2 instance id unique forever?](https://serverfault.com/a/58515)